# Can I create a trigger that involves a cursor on a table that the trigger is not made for?

Tags: sql, triggers, sqlanywhere

For example if I have a trigger for table employee. I want to create a cursor loop from the  table department. Then I want to take the attribute and insert it into the table company. I'm guessing the answer is no, because I get a runtime error that says table department cannot be found, but is there any way around this that gets the same effect?

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger AFTER INSERT
ORDER 1 ON dba.employee
REFERENCING NEW AS newRow
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    FOR myloop AS getIDCursor INSENSITIVE CURSOR FOR SELECT department_id FROM department
    DO 
       INSERT INTO company (...) VALUES (...);
    END FOR
END
```

Comment: Yes you can, but you need to declare that cursor before using it. Right after `begin`

Comment: A trigger might be executed a lot of times, and you cannot really control when it's being executed. I would **NEVER EVER** put a **CURSOR** inside a trigger! You're just asking for performance problems here.....

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using SQL like a procedural language? Just do:

```
INSERT INTO company SELECT department_id FROM department
```

No need for loops.